# How to fill an empty dataframe with default values using dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I get this correct output running the code immediately beneath it, counting the number of times"A" appears in the Element column of the `myData` data frame:

```
  Element counted
1       A       4
```

Code for above output:

```
library(dplyr)

myData = data.frame(Element = c("A","A","C","A","B","B","A"),Class = c(0,0,0,0,1,1,2))

myData %>% 
  filter(Element == 'A') %>%
  count(Element, name = 'counted')
```

However, I'd like to change the code so it returns the dataframe with count of 0 when it is run against a non-existing element.  I need this for a series of `ifelse(...)` statements that look back at that `myData` dataframe. So, when running this code for an element D that doesn't exist:

```
myData %>% 
  filter(Element == 'D') %>%
  count(Element, name = 'counted')
```

I'd like to get back:

```
  Element counted
1       D       0
```

Instead of this which the code currently generates:

```
[1] Element counted
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

In the complete code the D is an unknown, falling outside elements A - C. I'd like to return the 0 for any element outside A -C. I'd like to do this without including the element "D" in the factor levels.

Is there a slick way to this in `dplyr`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert `Element` to `factor` and give all levels you want, then set `.drop = FALSE` in `count()`:

```r
myData %>%
  mutate(Element = factor(Element, levels = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))) %>%
  count(Element, .drop = FALSE)

#   Element n
# 1       A 4
# 2       B 2
# 3       C 1
# 4       D 0
```

---

###### Update

It seens that you want to check whether a element is included in `Element`. If it is, then count its amount; otherwise, print 0. You could assign elements you wan to check outside and use the following code:

```r
x <- c('A', 'D')

myData %>%
  filter(Element %in% x) %>% 
  mutate(Element = factor(Element, levels = x)) %>%
  count(Element, .drop = FALSE)

#   Element n
# 1       A 4
# 2       D 0
```

---

###### Supplement

`.drop` is actually an argument in `group_by()`. This line

```r
%>% count(Element, .drop = FALSE)
```

is equivalent to

```r
%>% group_by(Element, .drop = FALSE) %>% tally()
```

under the hood. And `tally` can also be traced back to `summarise(n = n())`.

Comment: Thank you, however this requires putting the element D into the factor levels. In the complete code the D is an unknown, falling outside elements A - C. I'd like to return the 0 for any element outside A -C. Is there a way to do this w/o including D in the factor levels, and just returning the 1 row dataframe I show above where Element = D and counted = 0? (I also disagree that this is a duplicate, I'll see how I can challenge that)

Comment: @CuriousJorge-user9788072 I have reopened your question, please add the comment to your question to clarify your request.

Comment: @CuriousJorge-user9788072 Please see my update. Is it what you want?