# How to output a default dataframe using a conditional statement with dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, conditional-statements

Let's start with this `myData` dataframe generated by the code immediately beneath:

```
  Element Group
1       C     4
2       C     1
3       D     3
4       C     8

myData <-
  data.frame(
    Element = c("C","C","D","C"),
    Group = c(4,1,3,8)
  )
```

The `dplyr` code below counts the number of instances a selected element appears in the Element column of `myData`, but note that the code below is searching for an element "R" that doesn't appear in `myData`:

```
library(dplyr)
rCount <- myData %>% filter(Element == 'R') %>% count(Element, name = 'counted')
```

Here is what is returned when `rCount` is run against `myData`:

```
> rCount
[1] Element counted
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

How do I modify the `rCount` code so that the following default data frame is returned when element R  (or any other unlisted element) doesn't appear in the `myData` dataframe, using  a conditional statement with dplyr?

```
> rCount
  Element counted
1       R       0
```

Comment: How is this question different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73163579/how-to-fill-an-empty-dataframe-with-default-values-using-dplyr)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fill an empty dataframe with default values using dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73163579/how-to-fill-an-empty-dataframe-with-default-values-using-dplyr)

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to use a conditional statement with dplyr, as you show in your response Limey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a wrapper function to do the logic for you:

```
myCountFunc <- function(df, filterValue) {
  x <- df %>% 
    filter(Element == filterValue) %>% 
    count(Element, name="counted")
  if (nrow(x) == 0) {
    x <- tibble(Element=filterValue, counted=0)
  } 
  x
}
```

So that

```
myData %>% myCountFunc("R")
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  Element counted
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 R             0
```

and

```
myData %>%  myCountFunc("C")
  Element counted
1       C       3
```

Answer (score 3):

We could use `summarise` with conditional `sum()`:

```
library(dplyr)

rCount <- myData %>% 
  summarise(counted = sum(Element == 'R'), Element = 'R') %>%
  select(2,1)
```

```
 Element counted
1       R       0
```

Answer (score 0):

In R we have `factor` variables where we can set `levels` that are not present in the actual data.

In your case, we could change `Elements` into a factor with `R` as an additional `level` and then we can run `count(Element, .drop = FALSE)` to include factor levels that are not present in the data in count:

```r
library(dplyr)

myData %>% 
  mutate(Element = factor(Element, levels = c(unique(Element), "R"))) %>% 
  count(Element, .drop = FALSE)

#>   Element n
#> 1       C 3
#> 2       D 1
#> 3       R 0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>